# Problem in running more than 1 function in single function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.6

Hello Experts I have three different functions in postgresql

1. generates staff_id and total collection
2. generates staff_id and total new customer entry
3. generates staff_id and incentives of staffs

And now I want to generate summery report using this three functions in single function without rewriting all functions. I have written create temp table _t in every function so I am getting 
`relation "_t" already exists`. Is there any solution without altering those 3 functions because I don't want to declare different temp table to different functions neither want to write all three functions in single script only I want to call those 3 functions from single function.

Comment: Explain what each of your "generates ... " actually generates, and what is your intended use of each. The short answer NO you cannot create a the same temp table in each of your functions - unless you drop the previous one. But you may be able to avoid temp tables all together by modifying your functions to "returns table (*table description*)". Also post sample data that each generate produces and the results you want from them.

Comment: function number 1 results= |staff_id|staff_name|total_collection|
function number 2 results= |staff_id|staff_name|new_member_under_this_staff|
function number 3 results= |staff_id|staff_name|incentives_of_staff|

I want to create 1 function using this 3 functions and i have declare temp table _t in each function so i unable to run 1 single function.